# How can I load the same buffered image again multiple times onto my panel without having to create the same buffered image again?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

If this were to be my image:

```
private BufferedImage LVL140;

try

{        

LVL140 = ImageIO.read(new File("SplendorIm/LVL140.png"));

} catch (IOException e)

{

e.printStackTrace();

}

g.drawImage(LVL140,1050,0,null);
```

How can I load the same buffered image again multiple times onto my panel without having to create the same buffered image again?

Answer (score 0):

Once you loaded the image, use a `while {}` with a `Thread.sleep()` an the `g.drawImage()` inside it.

Here an example:

```java
public class DrawSystem extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private int width, height;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private boolean running;
    private Graphics2D g;

//Theses lines could be in a configuration, but let's do it here
    private void int FPS = 60;
    private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

    private BufferedImage LVL140;

    public DrawSystem(Dimension dimensions) {
        width = (int) dimensions.getWidth();
        height = (int) dimensions.getHeight();
            //here's your LVL140 image
        LVL140 = ImageIO.read(new File("SplendorIm/LVL140.png"));
    }

    //you just have to start the thred with (variable).start();
    @Override
        public void run() {
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
        running = true;

        long start;
        long elapsed;
        long wait;

        while(running) {
            start = System.nanoTime();

            draw();
            drawToScreen();

            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;
            if(wait > 0) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(wait);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //Draw pixels of "LVL140" on "img". You can draw others things without impact "LVL140" thanks to this
    private void draw() {
        g.drawImage(LVL140, 0, 0, null);
    }

//draw pixels of "img" on the JPanel.
    private void drawToScreen() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        if(g2 != null) {
            g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, null);
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you could use `addNotify()` and then start the Thread from there but don't embarassing yourself it's your firsts steps in java.

Juste create a `JFrame`, add the `DrawSystem` and do :

```java
DrawSystem sys = new DrawSystem(new Dimension(1000, 500));
<(your JFrame)>.add(sys);
Thread th = new Thread(sys);
//call the `run()` method
th.start();
```

As you can see, you create your BufferedImage once, then use it multiple time in the `draw()` method.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: But how would I drag a buffered image now?

Comment: @SoccerHalo_King123 has you can see, I have a `private BufferedImage LVL140`, and I initialize it in the constructor. You can add a setter for this, and set LVL140 as a different BufferedImage, and the `while` function will update it automatically.

Comment: How would that look? I have a mutator.

Comment: Add a method like `public void setImage(BufferedImage img) {LVL140 = img;}` (it's better to copy but you can find it by yourself...) then you call this method with your new image...